# CSS target <section> if it has any #id

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to target a  tag only if it contains and id.

Target this: `<section id="contact"></section>` but do not target this `<section></section>`

Something like this:

```
section#*{}
```

Comment: Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)... `section[id] {}`.